# How to access to dist files built by vue-cli?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

Please, help me understand, how to deal with such issue:
I use vue-cli and I want to build in dev mode some js file and then be able to access it by url like: http://localhost:8080/my-file.js

But by default, I can't do it in such way. As I understand, I have to override devServer option?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the JS files you want to include in a root folder called `/public/` and when `yarn build` runs (or `npm build` if you're using that) it will output them exactly as they are in `public` to the `dist` folder for reference like you're looking for.

Note that the `public` folder needs to be at the same level as your `src` folder - not inside the `src` folder.

Source: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#preload